# extern const variable doesn't initilized by function call

Tags: c++, constants, extern, linkage

I initialize two extern const variables in this way:

vars.hpp:

```
int init_a();
extern const int a;
extern const int b;
```

vars.cpp:

```
#include<vars.hpp>
int init_a() {
    return 1;
}
const int a = init_a();
const int b = 1;
```

stuff.hpp:

```
extern const int d;
extern const int e;
```

stuff.cpp:

```
const int d = a;
const int e = b;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<vars.hpp>
#include<stuff.hpp>

int main(){
    std::cout << a << b << d << e << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

The output is "1101", while I expect "1111". Could you please explain why value "d" is not shared among stuff.cpp and main.

If it is an normal initialization order problem, as far as I know, It should be 1111 (initialize vars.cpp first) or 1100 (initialize stuff.cpp first).

Comment: Looks like Static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: This dupe is the closest to the question I could find. Others deal with more sophisticated scenarios and types. Do post better ones if you can find them.

Comment: How do you know it's not shared? You're only observing it in `main`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is truly a duplicate. Answers to those questions seem to suggest that the output should be `1100` or `1111`, but it's not the case.